# Mixed Content Error on wordpress causing site unsecured

Tags: wordpress, security

I am experiencing difficulties with having facebook login working on my website. I suspect it is caused by my site not being fully secure as per results from whynopadlock.

The site is wordpress based. The only error I am left with is "A file with an insecure url of "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C700italic%2C800italic%2C400%2C300%2C600%2C700%2C800&subset=latin-ext%2Clatin&ver=4.9.8" was loaded on line: 76 of https://patateacher.com/."

Any idea how to deal with it? Many thanks

Comment: Put the error message you get with unsuccessful login here. Could be helpful.

Comment: facebook login? I am testing it for registration with facebook as it stopped working. Error from facebook: URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Comment: Just as the error say, had you put your redirect url after login into facebook app setting page? If not then copy paste this error message in google and you will find how to do it. Its common problem.

Comment: as I researched it, after recent updates facebook rejects any page that has padlock issues. I have noticed the problem just now, i didnt have it some months ago.  Hence my turn towards whynopadlock and dealing with insecure google fonts url.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I will recommend to use a plugin which will send your all requests as https instead of http 
[WORDPRESS HTTPS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/)

you are able to map URL's you want specifically to map with their https source as well. 
For more info please read its instructions, you can easily figure out its usage.

Comment: thank you for the idea. I managed to modify functions.php file from cpanel level. Its fully secure now